# Dashboard widget: getting version number from Info.plist

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard, dashcode

I'm writing a Dashboard widget in Dashcode, and on the back side, I've got a string for credits. I want to include the widget's version number in that string, but if possible, I want to programmatically grab it from the `CFBundleVersion` or `CFBundleShortVersionString` key in Info.plist to avoid having to change the number in multiple places if and when I update the widget.

Searches on Apple's [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Introduction/Introduction.html), Google and various forums have proven fruitless so far. What I'd like to know is whether there's a built-in way to do this that Apple included but forgot to mention (like `var version = widget.version();` or something), or whether my script will have to pull in and parse the entire plist before plucking out the one value I actually want.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer: use Dashcode's "data source" facility to read in Info.plist as an XML data source. From there, [this blog post](http://daringpuppet.blogspot.ca/2010/03/apple-dashcode-data-sources.html) showed me how to traverse the plist's structure and get the correct string (in this case, the fifth `<string>` element in the file, corresponding to `CFBundleShortVersionString`.

The function I ended up with:

```
function getWidgetVersion() {
    var dataSource = dashcode.getDataSource("infoPlist");
    var version = dataSource.selection().valueForKey("dict").valueForKey("string")[4]; // This line and the previous could probably be combined for the sake of brevity
    if (typeof(version) == 'string') {
        document.getElementById("creditsLabel").innerHTML += version; //I'll change this to just pass the number on
    }
}
```

Since the text of the `creditsLabel` div has already been started off with a localized string, I get a nice little label saying "Version 1.0".